# Queuing Theory m/m/1 system

Tags: probability, queueing-theory

2. A fast-food restaurant has one drive-through window. An average of 40 customers per hour arrives at the window. It takes an average of 1 minute to serve a customer. Assume that interarrival and service times are exponential.

   Q.What is the probability that a customer will have to wait before being served?

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get help if you [edit] the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Hint: how many minutes per hour is the window busy?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M/M/1_queue#Response_time

Answer (score 0):

I suggest having a read of the book [Stochastic Networks by Frank Kelly and Elena Yudovina](http://www.statslab.cam.ac.uk/~frank/STOCHNET/LNSN/book.pdf). In particular, you can find a section titled "$M/M/1$ Queues" on page 22 of the book.
There the invariant distribution is determined: writing $\lambda = 40/60 = 2/3 < 1$ for the arrival rate (with departure rate $1$), it is given by
$$ \pi(j) = (1 - \lambda) \cdot \lambda^j
\quad\text{for}\quad
j = 0,1,2,... \, .$$
This is valid if and only if $\lambda < 1$. (For $\lambda > 1$ one can show that no invariant distribution exists: there is a unique invariant measure, up to scaling, but this measure is not summable.)

Now, once we know the invariant distribution, we're done: "customer wait" equals "queue non-empty". So, in equilibrium,
$$ P(\text{customer does not have to wait}) = P(\text{queue empty}) = \pi(0) = 1 - \lambda, $$
and hence your probability in question is $\lambda = 2/3$.

Comment: Since the λ is 2/3, so while calculating the P(queue empty) = 1- λ, the probability should be 1 - 2/3 = 1/3

Comment: I think there's a little bit of confusion with the terminology. Here "empty" means that the person **won't have to wait**. Your OP asks "what is the probability that a customer *will* have to wait". "Will wait" means "non-empty", and $P(\text{non-empty}) = 1 - P(\text{empty})$. Does that clear it up for you? If not, feel free to ask for clarification :)